# How to sort Ruby Hash based on date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a hash object with the following structure:

```
{"action1"=>
  {"2014-08-20"=>0,
   "2014-07-26"=>1,
   "2014-07-31"=>1
  },
 "action2"=>
  {"2014-08-01"=>2,
   "2014-08-20"=>2,
   "2014-07-25"=>2,
   "2014-08-06"=>1,
   "2014-08-21"=>1
 }
 "action3"=>
  {"2014-07-30"=>2,
   "2014-07-31"=>1,
   "2014-07-22"=>1,
  }
}
```

I want to sort the hash based on the date and return back a Hash(Not array). The final result should be:

```
{"action1"=>
  {"2014-07-26"=>1,
   "2014-07-31"=>1,
   "2014-08-20"=>0
  },
 "action2"=>
  {"2014-07-25"=>2,
   "2014-08-01"=>2,
   "2014-08-06"=>2,
   "2014-08-20"=>1,
   "2014-08-21"=>1
 }
 "action3"=>
  {"2014-07-22"=>1,
   "2014-07-30"=>2,
   "2014-07-31"=>1
  }
}
```

Comment: You need a comma after `}`, before `"ation3"=>`.  No reply req'd.; I'll delete this comment once you've seen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the hash, and for each value, sort.

```
h = {"action1"=>
  {"2014-08-20"=>0,
   "2014-07-26"=>1,
   "2014-07-31"=>1
  },
 "action2"=>
  {"2014-08-01"=>2,
   "2014-08-20"=>2,
   "2014-07-25"=>2,
   "2014-08-06"=>1,
   "2014-08-21"=>1
 },
 "action3"=>
  {"2014-07-30"=>2,
   "2014-07-31"=>1,
   "2014-07-22"=>1,
  }
}

h.each do |k, v|
    h[k] = Hash[v.sort]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need:

```
h.each { |k,v| h[k] = v.sort.to_h }
  #=> {"action1"=>{"2014-07-26"=>1, "2014-07-31"=>1, "2014-08-20"=>0},
  #    "action2"=>{"2014-07-25"=>2, "2014-08-01"=>2, "2014-08-06"=>1,
  #       "2014-08-20"=>2, "2014-08-21"=>1},
  #    "action3"=>{"2014-07-22"=>1, "2014-07-30"=>2, "2014-07-31"=>1}}
```

[Hash#to_h](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-to_h) appeared in Ruby 2.0. For earlier versions, use the class method [Hash::[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D): i.e., replace `v.sort.to_h` with `Hash[v.sort]`.

Comment: Thanks for your willing to help. Aw, I'm getting an error: undefined method `to_h' for #<Array>. I'm using Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to iterate your hash and fetch the value than you need to apply **sort_by** function on each value so  you will get your result

```
hashName.each do |key, hash|
  Hash[hashName.sort_by{|k,v| k}]
end
```